# sorting list after adding and replacing value

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I recently began to learning python and am currently working with list/loops. On the list below, I added *(append)mercedes*, *replaced honda with ford* and *inserted wolkswagen*. When I ran the code, the list is sorted correctly but the new vehicles (ford, toyota and wolkswagen) are on top of the list instead.

**Code**

```
cars = ['honda', 'acura', 'bmw', 'bugatti', 'Toyota']
cars.append('mercedes')
cars[0] = 'Ford'
cars.insert(1, 'Wolkswagen')
cars.sort()
for car in cars:
    print (car.title() + ", is just a regular car")
```

**Result**

```
Ford, is just a regular car
Toyota, is just a regular car
Wolkswagen, is just a regular car
Acura, is just a regular car
Bmw, is just a regular car
Bugatti, is just a regular car
Mercedes, is just a regular car
```

Comment: Hint: case matters to `sort()` (e.g. `Toyota` comes before `toyota`).

Comment: geez! you're correct. I didn't noticed I had some words capitalized, simple answer. I had read there was something about caps words but didn't read what was the result. Thanks

Comment: @Darwinsm. Feel free to select an answer. Both answers point this out. It gets you a couple of points and marks your question as answered for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uppercase letters come before lowercase letters when sorting strings lexicographically. You need to make sure all the names are in the same case, or sort them ignoring case in order to get consistent results.

E.g:

```
cars = sorted(s.title() for s in cars)
for car in cars:
  print (car + ", is just a regular car")
```

Comment: This will reformat all the car names and make a copy of the list. Why not just use `key`?

Comment: I haven't gotten there yet, I am still learning the basics. My profession is graphic design/video/ web, so I am switching to programming beginning with python.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python [sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) is case-sensitive, you need to explicitly make the sort insensitive with a sort key. A [sort key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) is a function that generates the objects that will actually be sorted from the objects in your list. For example:

```
cars.sort(key=str.casefold)
```

[`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) accepts a string and turns it into lowercase, so all your strings will be sorted as if they were lowercase. The originals will be left untouched.

If you are not using any non-Latin characters, use [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) should work fine as well.

Once you have your list sorted properly, you can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module to ensure that future elements are inserted correctly without having to re-sort the whole thing.